# Rename root tag only using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to rename root tag of below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <aaa>
      <bbb>
         <ccc>123</ccc>
         <ggg>2010.2</ggg>
      </bbb>
   </aaa>
   <ddd>
      <eee>112</eee>
      <fff>234</fff>
   </ddd>
   <ddd>
      <eee>456</eee>
      <fff>345</fff>
   </ddd>
</root>
```

I'm trying to get below xml using xslt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zzz xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <aaa>
      <bbb>
         <ccc>123</ccc>
         <ggg>2010.2</ggg>
      </bbb>
   </aaa>
   <ddd>
      <eee>112</eee>
      <fff>234</fff>
   </ddd>
   <ddd>
      <eee>456</eee>
      <fff>345</fff>
   </ddd>
</zzz>
```

I tried with below XSLT to get above xml.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <zzz>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </zzz>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And return the same response similar to input.

But, if root tag has no namespace, this xslt return the expected response.

Could someone please help me.

Comment: Your question is not clear. A namespace is part of the name; if you want to rename the root element, you must specify what namespace - if any - the new name should use. It's also not clear what you mean by "dynamically" in your comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to rename the root element while keeping its original namespace, you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- rename root (keep namespace) -->
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="zzz" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following script:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:syn="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="syn:root">
    <xsl:element name="zzz" namespace="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The required changes are:

- Include the default source namespace in the stylesheet tag,
  giving it some name (I used *syn*).
- Change matching from `root` to `syn:root`.
- Create the main element (*zzz*) with namespace specification.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any way to get namespace dynamically?

Comment: Your `$ns` variable will contain the generic XML namespace. See your result here: http://xsltransform.net/a9GiwB